# List S3 Buckets from a specific region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am using AWS Ruby SDK v2 to get S3 Bucket names. Is there a way to get S3 buckets from a specific region?

The way I do it now:

```
buckets = s3_client.list_buckets.buckets.map(&:name)
buckets.select { |name| s3_client.get_bucket_location(:bucket => name).location_constraint == @region }
```

This gets all the buckets I have in  `buckets`. Then I filter ones that are from region I specified with `@region`.

I would like to be able to do this with making only one request through AWS SDK. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You could build a hacky solution by maintaining an independent DB mapping of bucket to region, I guess.

Comment: Doesn't S3 client require a region parameter when instantiating? (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html) Does it still return all the buckets regardless of the region?

Comment: Yes, it does, and yes, it does... but no matter which endpoint you interrogate, all S3 regions are aware of the existence of all buckets, presumably at least in part because of the global design of the bucket namespace.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Well I solved this with the PHP SDK using *client*->getBucketLocation(). With the multiRegion client you can just use the 'LocationConstraint', with the standard single region client I can handle this by catching the Exception for non-defined Regions.

That said, with the RubySDK (which I'm less familiar with) Amazon suggests you use this (as an example):

```
require 'aws-sdk-s3'  # v2: require 'aws-sdk'

region = 'us-west-2'
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: region)

s3.buckets.limit(50).each do |b|
  if s3.client.get_bucket_location(bucket: b.name).location_constraint == region
    puts "#{b.name}"
  end
end
```

More information can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-get-buckets-in-region.html#aws-ruby-sdk-s3-example-get-buckets-in-region

Comment: Thanks @sdmeyers! I finally resorted to something like you wrote, but I was interested in making only one request. E.g. passing in region name when fetching buckets and be done in one request.